# Slipt Formula String

Tags: java, string, split

This is my code to split a formula to get terms, for example formula is "CH3O2". I need to split it so I get term('C',1) , term('H',3) , term('O',2). Later these would be stored in ArrayList.

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++){
           if(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i)))
           {
            String [] st = s.split(",");
            System.out.println(st);
            }
           }
```

Comment: Is there a question? Or are you just randomly posting code?

Comment: What about `NaCl`? You can't just give one example and expect a complete solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement/question was not completely clear. Assuming your input had no commas in it ( as in your example "CH3O2") it would not split with `String.split`. The following example handles the intent of your conundrum.

```
public class StackOverflow
{
  private static final String testString = "CH3O2";

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<String> terms = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < testString.length(); i++)
    {
      if (Character.isUpperCase(testString.charAt(i)))
      {
        if (i + 1 < testString.length()
            && Character.isDigit(testString.charAt(i + 1)))
        {
          terms.add(testString.charAt(i) + "," + testString.charAt(i + 1));
          i++;
          continue;
        }
        terms.add(testString.charAt(i) + ",1");
      }
    }
    for (String s : terms)
    {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it as the answer, Thanks!